# Как сделать в bootstrap такую верстку?

Tags: bootstrap

Как сделать в bootstrap такую верстку?

[image: Скрин]

Comment: "Как сделать такую вёрстку" это какая-то жёсткая постановка вопроса...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну берешь стандартные средства bootstrap и в верстаешь. Шрифт свой воткни, картинки контрастные подбери и будет тебе счастье. Иконки вроде эти используются http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ .  bootstrap  дает инструменты что бы это делать, а не готовые сайты=).

Comment: Да, это понятно все. Нужен пример грида. Как расположить правильно .row .col

Comment: ну тебе тут не кто бесплатно сайт не напишет)))) Вот на держи пример куска, можно сказать на котах показывают <div class="container">
 <div class="col-sm-7">
  <div style="
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: 1rem;
  "></div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-5">
  <div style="
  height: calc(200px - 1rem);
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: 1rem;
  margin-left: 0;
  "></div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-5">
  <div style="
  height: calc(200px - 1rem);
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: 1rem;
  margin-left: 0;"></div></div></div>